# How can I pass varargs to lua files?

Tags: lua

In World of Warcraft addons, a table is passed as the second vararg:

```
-- This is often at the top of WoW lua files
local AddonTable = select(2, ...)
```

Is there a way to do that with regular lua? I'm attempting to write some unit tests with minimal changes to my current code. So far when I just use require, I can use `select(1, ...)` to get the first parameter to require (the module), but I can't seem to figure out how to populate the second argument.

Update:

Instead of using `require`, I can use `loadfile` to do what I need. When World Of Warcraft loads an addon, it passes the name of the addon and a table that can be populated with your addon's functions. I can reproduce that functionality with this code:

```
local addon = loadfile('MyAddon.lua')
local AddonTable = {}
addon('AddonName', AddonTable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase your question:

First understand that all that is happening in wow is your lua file is being lua_loadfile'd, then the resulting closure is being executed with 2 parameters on the stack.

This is similar to what require is doing from an outside perspective, but when you think it through it is different.

Require returns the module - that is the equivalent to the WoW table that is the 2nd arguement. The parameter to require (the name of the module) is the equivalent of the first.

Answer (score 3):

also, the select call is unnecessay. Just do:
`local AddonName , AddonTable = ...`

Comment: I don't need to use AddonName, I just need to pass it for compatibility.

Comment: still cheaper to assign it (and not use it) than to call select; but I guess I'm just nit-picking... Common practice is to assign throw away values to _ (such as when you use string.find), but if you know their meaning, you might as well give them a name...